# Create a grammar for the language $L =\{a^n b^{n/2} c^n\mid n\equiv 0\pmod{2}\}$

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammar

I am interested in a grammar for the language L which defined as follows: $$ L=\left\{ { a }^{ n }{ b }^{ n/2 }{ c }^{ n }\mid n\bmod2=0,\quad n\in\mathbb N \right\}  $$ My idea is to substitute n with 2m because only even integers are accepted, which are completely divisible by 2. So that I would come to the following: $$ L=\left\{ { a }^{ 2m }{ b }^{ m }{ c }^{ 2m }\mid m\in \mathbb N \right\}  $$ The grammar generates words, such as aabcc, aaaabbcccc.

My attempts to construct a clever grammar for the language L have not been successful so far. I am very curious if anyone can help me.

Comment: Do you know the grammar for $\{a^nb^nc^n\}?$? It's in the wikipedia article for formal grammars. Try to write a variation. There is no context-free grammar, I believe. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar

Comment: Hi Mr. Andrews, if I'm not mistaken, then this might be the grammar for L:
$$ S -> aaBScc $$
$$ S -> aabcc $$
$$ Ba -> aB $$
$$ Bb -> bb $$

Comment: My only problem with that grammar  is that it doesn't include the empty string. For me, $\mathbb N$ contains $0.$ The wikipedia example explicitly is defining for $n\geq 1,$ so there is no problem there, but your case you have to be careful if you allow $n=0.$

Comment: That the language $L$ is not context-free can be seen by noting that $L' = \{a^nb^nc^n \mid n \geq 0 \}$ is not context-free, and context-free languages are closed under substitutions.  If we apply the substitution $R_a = a$, $R_b = bb$, and $R_c = c$ to $L$, we get $L'$.